# Which one is anterior to the other?

Tags: tense

> If she **beats** (a) him **he’ll claim** (b) she **cheated** (c).
>  (The
>   Cambridge Grammar of the English Language)

The time of (c) is certainly earlier than (b). But which one is earlier between (a) and (b)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) is the earlier.  The sentence is predicting something that will happen after she has beaten him.

Answer (score 1):

A comes before B.  He will only make the claim after she beats him, yes?